# ODBC Data source Not Found

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to connect to a Windows SQL Server from a Windows Server 2016 (with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server installed) through Sqlalchemy and Python 3.6.2.
As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/admin/odbc-data-source-administrator?view=sql-server-ver15) I created a data source in the Odbc Data Source Administrator

[image: ODBC_DATA_SOURCE]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I cannot use pyodbc but I'm able to connect and run queries using it.
I'm also able to connect to the database and run queries using SQL Server Management Studio from the Windows Server.

What I'm trying:

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://DB_INSTANCE_ADDRESS/DB_NAME?driver=ODBC_DATA_SOURCE?Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

What I've got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in table_names
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 401, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3220, in table_names
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2972, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self.connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3204, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3283, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3254, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2101, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Comment: Did you create the User DSN when logged in to the Public user's desktop? Have you tried creating it as a System DSN yet?

Comment: Try `mssql+pyodbc://@ODBC_DATA_SOURCE`

Comment: Applying @GordThompson advice solved the connection issue. Thank you